# .click on parent container only, not affecting child containers

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating an overlay/modal/pop-up on my site.

When the user clicks a button the overlay appears. To *close* the overlay I wish for the user to be able to click anywhere on the outside area of the page (e.g the black opacity area in my example).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ewexsqr/

I have set the following:

```
$('.overlay-wrapper').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity','0');
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index','-100');
    });
```

This works fine, **however** it is also affecting clicking inside the `.overlay-content` div, a child of `.overlay-wrapper`. I want the user to be able to click/highlight etc inside the content box and NOT trigger the click event.

How can I make this click event not apply to the inner content?

Comment: Find an explanation of the problem, how to solve it and your updated, working fiddle in my answer below. It uses the method jQuery ships with to solve the problem.

Comment: Is your question answered now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `event.target`, if it's `.overlay-content`, or a descendant of `.overlay-content`, don't close the popup (you can use `.closest()` since it'll test itself):

```
var $target = $( e.target );

if ( $target.closest( '.overlay-content' ).length ) {
    return true;   
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ewexsqr/1/)

Comment: Removed my answer as this one was more complete.

Comment: jQuery has a native method for this called `event.stopPropagation()` - see my answer below. Why not use it?

Comment: the `event` object is part of the dom, it's not specific to jQuery. jQuery only normalises some of its properties. You can use it, but if you've registered any other click handlers on parent elements, and need them to fire, they won't.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click handler to the overlay itself with `false`

```
$('.overlay-content').click(false);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity','1');
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index','100');
    });
    $('.overlay-content').click(false);
    $('.overlay-wrapper').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity','0');
        $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index','-100');
    });
});
```

```css
.button{background-color:orange;color:#fff;padding:10px;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;}
.overlay-wrapper {
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-100;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.overlay-content{
    border:1px dotted white;
    padding:10px;
    margin:50px;
    background-color:#000;
    cursor:default;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1,p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#fff;
}
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image:url('http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/digital_art/2d/31494_2d_funky_colorful.jpg');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay-content">
         <h1>Clicking inside this box should *do NOTHING*</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue ut felis et euismod. Donec congue neque nec nibh blandit porta. Mauris velit sapien, viverra quis accumsan sit amet, rhoncus eu lacus. Maecenas suscipit diam in iaculis interdum. Nulla at eros non nulla laoreet fermentum nec aliquet odio. Nam sed velit eget lacus malesuada aliquet sed vel odio. In ac magna accumsan tellus consequat iaculis. Proin facilisis lorem non ex molestie feugiat. Curabitur sodales ligula elit. Aenean mollis, velit sed interdum rhoncus, enim nulla tincidunt tortor, non efficitur odio lacus non neque. Sed venenatis sit amet enim nec dapibus. Donec tempor viverra iaculis. Sed nec sapien non nisl finibus facilisis.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Or**, utilize `event.target`

```
if (!$(event.target).closest('.overlay-content').length)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index', '100');
  });

  $('.overlay-wrapper').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.overlay-content').length) {
      $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity', '0');
      $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index', '-100');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay-content {
  border: 1px dotted white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: default;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/digital_art/2d/31494_2d_funky_colorful.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h1>Clicking inside this box should *do NOTHING*</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue ut felis et euismod. Donec congue neque nec nibh blandit porta. Mauris velit sapien, viverra quis accumsan sit amet, rhoncus eu lacus. Maecenas suscipit diam in iaculis interdum.
      Nulla at eros non nulla laoreet fermentum nec aliquet odio. Nam sed velit eget lacus malesuada aliquet sed vel odio. In ac magna accumsan tellus consequat iaculis. Proin facilisis lorem non ex molestie feugiat. Curabitur sodales ligula elit. Aenean
      mollis, velit sed interdum rhoncus, enim nulla tincidunt tortor, non efficitur odio lacus non neque. Sed venenatis sit amet enim nec dapibus. Donec tempor viverra iaculis. Sed nec sapien non nisl finibus facilisis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Attempted but does not work (no longer closes regardless of click location) https://jsfiddle.net/7ewexsqr/2/

Comment: @Francesca, you only need the if in the handler itself. https://jsfiddle.net/7ewexsqr/3/

Answer (score 0):

### Where it comes from

Your problem originates in so-called **[event bubbling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110883/how-does-event-bubbling-generally-work-and-is-it-synonym-to-event-propagation#110898)**.

### How to solve it

There is a [specific jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to solve exactly this. Use

```
$('.overlay-content').on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

This stops the click event inside your overlay content to bubble to the `.overlay-wrapper` and thus, does not trigger its click function any more.

### Working example, using your code

https://jsfiddle.net/7ewexsqr/5/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the target is same.

```
if( e.target != this ) 
         return;
```

**Try this:**

```
$('.overlay-wrapper').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != this)
      return;
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index', '-100');
  });
```

**Snippets:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index', '100');
  });

  $('.overlay-wrapper').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != this)
      return;
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.overlay-wrapper').css('z-index', '-100');
  });

});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.overlay-content {
  border: 1px dotted white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: default;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.imgbase.info/images/safe-wallpapers/digital_art/2d/31494_2d_funky_colorful.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h1>Clicking inside this box should *do NOTHING*</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue ut felis et euismod. Donec congue neque nec nibh blandit porta. Mauris velit sapien, viverra quis accumsan sit amet, rhoncus eu lacus. Maecenas suscipit diam in iaculis interdum.
      Nulla at eros non nulla laoreet fermentum nec aliquet odio. Nam sed velit eget lacus malesuada aliquet sed vel odio. In ac magna accumsan tellus consequat iaculis. Proin facilisis lorem non ex molestie feugiat. Curabitur sodales ligula elit. Aenean
      mollis, velit sed interdum rhoncus, enim nulla tincidunt tortor, non efficitur odio lacus non neque. Sed venenatis sit amet enim nec dapibus. Donec tempor viverra iaculis. Sed nec sapien non nisl finibus facilisis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers propose for you to write some JavaScript which may work but it's not a proper way to handle this problem.

The simplest and most effective way is to move the `overlay-content`div outside of `overlay-wrapper` div and than position it propery with CSS.

```
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div class="overlay-wrapper">

</div>
<div class="overlay-content">
  <h1>Clicking inside this box should *do NOTHING*</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse   congue ut felis et euismod. Donec congue neque nec nibh blandit porta. Mauris velit sapien, viverra quis accumsan sit amet, rhoncus eu lacus. Maecenas suscipit diam in iaculis interdum. Nulla at eros non nulla laoreet fermentum nec aliquet odio. Nam sed velit eget lacus malesuada aliquet sed vel odio. In ac magna accumsan tellus consequat iaculis. Proin facilisis lorem non ex molestie feugiat. Curabitur sodales ligula elit. Aenean mollis, velit sed interdum rhoncus, enim nulla tincidunt tortor, non efficitur odio lacus non neque. Sed venenatis sit amet enim nec dapibus. Donec tempor viverra iaculis. Sed nec sapien non nisl finibus facilisis.    </p>
</div>
```

and than you should change the opacity and z-index on `overlay-content` div